# Python: How to create a list of integers depending on a specific distribution

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Is there a way in python/numpy/scipy to create dynamically a list of integers in a specific range, which can vary and in which the numbers are ordererd depending on a distribtuin, like nomral(gaussian), exponential, linear. I imagine something

```
like for range 3:

[1,2,3]
[2,1,2]
[1,2,1]
[3,2,1]


for range 4:

[1,2,3,4]
[2,1,1,2]
[1,2,2,1]
[4,3,2,1]

for range 5:

[1,2,3,4,5]
[2,1,0,1,2]
[1,2,3,2,1]
[5,4,3,2,1]
```

Comment: Integer distributions in range - yes, see `numpy.info(numpy.random)`. Ordered - nothing I am aware of, you would have to write that yourself.

Comment: What must be the output for a bigger number say `range=7`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use a bit of trickery using `np.minimum` to generate the symmetrical version in third row. The second row is just a complement of the third row subtracted from `3`. The first and last rows are just ranges starting from `1`  till `n` and flipped version of it respectively.

Thus, we would have one approach after row-stacking those rows to have a `2D` array, like so -

```
def ranged_arr(n):
    r = np.arange(n)+1
    row3 = np.minimum(r,r[::-1])
    return np.c_[r, 3-row3, row3, r[::-1]].T
```

We could also use `np.row_stack` to do the stacking -

```
np.row_stack((r, 3-row3, row3, r[::-1]))
```

Sample runs -

```
In [106]: ranged_arr(n=3)
Out[106]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 1],
       [3, 2, 1]])

In [107]: ranged_arr(n=4)
Out[107]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 1, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 2, 1],
       [4, 3, 2, 1]])

In [108]: ranged_arr(n=5)
Out[108]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [2, 1, 0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3, 2, 1],
       [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]])
```